# How do I tell tomcat to support CORS for static content?

Tags: tomcat, static, cors

This question: [Servers that supports CORS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4952838/servers-that-supports-cors) was about regular servlets; and I do know how to set headers to control CORS.

My question is how do I configure Tomcat to serve static content under CORS restrictions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a Tomcat filter for adding CORS support: https://bitbucket.org/jsumners/corsfilter

Comment: https://wiki.magnolia-cms.com/display/WIKI/CORS+filter+documentation

Answer (score 15):

Starting with Tomcat 7.0.41, you can easily control CORS behavior via a built-in filter.

References:

- [Tomcat 7](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/filter.html#CORS_Filter)
- [Tomcat 9](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/filter.html#CORS_Filter)

Pretty much the only thing you have to do is edit the global `web.xml` in `CATALINA_HOME/conf` and add the filter definition:

```
     <!-- ================== Built In Filter Definitions ===================== -->

      ...

     <filter>
       <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
       <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
     </filter>
     <filter-mapping>
       <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
       <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
     </filter-mapping>

    <!-- ==================== Built In Filter Mappings ====================== -->
```

Be aware, though, that Firefox does not like `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` and requests with credentials (cookies): [*when responding to a credentialed request,  server must specify a domain, and cannot use wild carding.*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Requests_with_credentials)

If you want to debugs requests in this situation, please be aware that CORS headers are only sent if there is a cross-origin request according to this flow-chart: [image: CORS flow chart]

(tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/images/cors-flowchart.png)

Answer (score 1):

*Hi Vlad! This is a very late response, by now you must have figured it all out. In case anyone else comes across the same question, this is the answer.*

Obviously, you know about the CORS filter and that Tomcat filters will be applied only to servlets.

To make all static content go through *some* servlet, Tomcat has a special **DefaultServet** - this is what you are looking for.

Basically, we just need to enabled it in deployment descriptor file (like WEB-INF/web.xml), for example like this:

```
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>


<servlet>
  <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

This way Tomcat filters, in our case CORS filter will be enabled for static content.

To test, for CORS filter to actually set headers, such as **Access-Control-Allow-Origin**, we will need to add some other header, like **Origin** in request.
For example:

```
curl -H 'Origin: http://localhost/test' -i http://myserver/crossOrigin.resource
```

This way you will see something like:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost/test
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Accept-Ranges: bytes
...
```

Comment: This was not required in my setup with Tomcat 8.5. I just had to apply the solution of @johannes-jander. I went into the trap that the CORS filter is very intelligent when to send the headers and when not (see https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/images/cors-flowchart.png). Just doing a GET from the browser will not show the headers at all, because it is not a cross-origin request.